# count the number of occurrences of a specific character in array C++

Tags: c++

```
// i have the array here and i need to count the number of males and females 
char gender[] = { 'F', 'M', 'F', 'F', 'M', 'F' };
```

i have been using this type of function to count integers in arrays but it doesnt seem to work for
when i need to count char type variables in an array. Anyone knows what i'm doing wrong?

```
 template <class T>
    nbgender(T table[], int arraysize, char gender,  T * ptr_nbM )
   {
     T male = 0;
     for(int i = 1; i < arraysize; i++)
        if (table[i] == 'M')
             male =+ 1;
     *ptr_nbM = male;        
  
   }
```

this is the error i get if i attempt to call the function:

```
99  [Error] no matching function for call to 'nbgender(char [6], int&, char, int*)'
```

Comment: Can you post the code you are using to call the function?

Answer (score 1):

Your current function does not work because `table` and `ptr_nbM` are of different types (`char != int`). To fix this, you likely want different template types for the counter and for the array.

```
template <typename TableType, typename CounterType>
void nbgender(TableType table[], int arraysize, char gender, CounterType *ptr_nbM) {
  ...
}
```